# Deploying Go app to heroku error

Tags: heroku, go, makefile

I refactored my code file structure to be under the cmd folder since I now added a worker and now it has this structure:

[image]

All the go files are inside the folders so in order to install it locally I use '*make install*' which I configured to *go install* each package.
But when I try to push to Heroku it just runs *go install* and so I get the error:

> Running: go install -v -tags heroku .  can't load package: package
>   github.com/heroku/secretly-sender: no buildable Go source files in
>   /tmp/tmp.pTW8NahxGm/.go/src/github.com/heroku/secretly-sender

How can I fix this?
Here are my other files

Procfile:

```
web: secretly-sender-web
worker: secretly-sender-worker
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR "/opt"

ADD .docker_build/secretly-sender /opt/bin/secretly-sender/cmd
ADD ./templates /opt/templates
ADD ./static /opt/static

CMD ["/opt/bin/secretly-sender/cmd"]
```

Makefile

```
GO_BUILD_ENV := GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
DOCKER_BUILD=$(shell pwd)/.docker_build
DOCKER_CMD=$(DOCKER_BUILD)/secretly-sender/cmd

$(DOCKER_CMD): clean
    mkdir -p $(DOCKER_BUILD)
    $(GO_BUILD_ENV) go build -v -o $(DOCKER_CMD) .

clean:
    rm -rf $(DOCKER_BUILD)

heroku: $(DOCKER_CMD)
    heroku container:push web
    heroku container:push worker

install:
    go install github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/cmd/secretly-sender-web
    go install github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/cmd/secretly-sender-worker
    go install github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/shared

build:
    go build github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/cmd/secretly-sender-web
    go build github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/cmd/secretly-sender-worker
    go build github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/shared
```

I don't really understand what these files and path mean so I still couldn't solve my issue
Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see any `.go` files in your project.

Comment: They are inside the folders

Comment: You need at least one `.go` file in the root of your project which must be `package main`

Comment: But I want the web dynos to run the main package inside secretly-sender-web. Will that still work?

Comment: Nah, need at least one `main` go program. What you can do is include your go files within those folders with `include "github.com/heroku/secretly-sender/cmd/secretly-sender-web"` as long as the `secretly-sender-web` is not `package main`

Comment: Your options are:

 - Make those `go` files in the sub folders their own packages and include into a `main.go` file located in the root of your project.

- Change your layout so all `go` files are in the root of your project (all with `package main`

Comment: But look at my procfile. How can I have the web dyno run the main in cmd/secretly-sender-web and the worker dyno run the cmd/secretly-sender-worker. I structured it like this because I read it was a good practice but I don't get how they make this work.

Comment: Hm, sorry but I'm not sure about proc files and I've never done anything like that. As far as I know, if you want to run any kind of `go` file, it needs to be of package `main`.

Comment: Yes, they are. secretly-sender-web and secretly-sender-worker they each have a main. I told the procfile to execute those files and that works but I can't deploy it to Heroku :/ Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to add this:

```
"heroku": {
    "install": [
        "./cmd/..."
    ]
},
```

to vendor/vendor.json
:D